# Unable to find instance for a cloned player (Unet) in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I am making a quake style game and i'm implementing multiplayer currently. there are jump pads where if the gameObject=("Player(Clone)") enters the trigger it is sent flying. In unet (Unity Multiplayer) when you launch and join in it creates your GameObject as "Player(Clone)".

the issue now is that when a second player joins and jumps on the jump pad (Enters the trigger) Nothing happens. But the host (player 1) can. Here is the code for the jump pad recognizing the GameObject. I've been bashing my brain over this trying out different methods like "Find.FindGameObjectsWithTag".

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class JumpPad : MonoBehaviour {

QuakeJump fpsinput;
public float power;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider mycollision)
{
    {
        fpsinput = 
GameObject.Find("Player(Clone)").GetComponent<QuakeJump>();
        if (mycollision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            fpsinput.playerVelocity = transform.up * power;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Edit: I've also noticed that when player 2 jumps on the pad, nothing happens to him but Player 1 (host) gets launched into the air without even stepping on the pad.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of my findings:

1. `GameObject.Find("Player(Clone)")` will only get one gameobject. So, if there's 2 player, you are getting only one and it may be the first player.
2. If you are using **NetworkTransform** and the **NetworkIdentity** of player is not set to **Local Player Authority**, it wouldn't work, as the server will control the transform.
3. You'll also need to make sure if the rigidbody is synced over network.

However, I would suggest to use **Command** and **RPCClient** to sync all the players over network. For example, when a player enters the trigger, send RPC to all the clients so that they also update the transform of the player in their instances.
Please take a look at the Networking tutorials in depth here: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking

Comment: I'm very sure at this point its number 1), I'm just starting on networking so I'm unsure  what RPCClient and all that is. But what kind of method (besides rpc) would you use to solve number 1)?

Comment: You need to get the quakeJump component from the player which has entered the trigger. So, you can use the code like this: https://pastebin.com/baU5qyfb  
Still, it won't work, if you don't make sure of the 2nd point. –

Comment: my Network Identity is set to local player authority and when I wrote what you pasted in my code, it had no affect, its still at the current state where if the host jumps on the pad he can launch, and if any other player jumps on it the player wont launch but the host will launch even if he isnt on the pad.

Comment: If it's okay with you, can you please share me the project? I want to take a look. In multiplayer it can go wrong in many places.